# How to remove string from matrix elements?

Tags: matrix

I have a matrix that contains data I need, but there is string attached to some of the numbers that I need. For example:

{Input0, Output0 1.34, Output1 3.45}
{Input1, Output2 3.55, Output3 2.00}

Is there a way I can remove the words Input/Output from the file so I have a matrix of just numbers, rather than doing it manually?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is yes, but the details matter. Could you show us the `FullForm` of the expression you wish to transform? It's not clear whether your "strings" are parts of actual strings or symbols. Are your elements like `"Output0 1.34"` or `Times[Output0, 1.34]`?

Comment: "string attached to some of the numbers". Humm. this looks like an XY question.   May be try to find out how did these strings get into the Matrix and get stuck to the number in the first place and correct that instead? Did you generate this Matrix or did  it come from some external source?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. I would request you to respond to comments so far so that you can be assisted further. If you are new to Mathematica, then the introductory [book] written by the inventor is a good starting point. Best of luck.

Comment: Hi Nasser - it came from an external source, so I'm stuck with the string in the matrix. 

@JohnDoty - I won't upload the whole array as it's quite large, but the FullForm gives: 

List["Input0", "Output0 1.34, "Output1 3.45"], List["Input1", "Output2 3.55", "Output3 2.00"]

etc.

Comment: Missing [link](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) for the book. Apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract the "Input" number as a string:

```
extInput[s_] := StringReplace[s, "Input" -> ""]
```

And the "Output" result:

```
extOutput[s_] := StringReplace[s, RegularExpression["Output[0-9]* "] -> ""]
```

These functions leave unrecognized inputs alone, so just apply them both to the input strings. Convert to numbers:

```
ts[s_] := ImportString[extOutput[extInput[s]], "Table"][[1, 1]]
```

`Map` this to your table:

```
t = {List["Input0", "Output0 1.34", "Output1 3.45"],
 List["Input1", "Output2 3.55", "Output3 2.00"] }
Map[ts, t, {2}]
```

yielding:

```
{{0, 1.34, 3.45}, {1, 3.55, 2.}}
```

You may also do the numeric conversion with `ToExpression` rather than `ImportString`, but that will execute any syntactically valid *Mathematica* expression, which could cause unexpected trouble.

Comment: That's great - thank you so much.